# Estimating E[Y] given moments for X|Y=0, X|Y>0, and X

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation, bayesian

I have some data set where

```
X: time spent using Feature 1

Y: time spent using Feature 2 (a subfeature of Feature 1)
```

Note that the two variables are always non-negative, and also, Feature 2 is located inside of Feature 1, so if I use Feature 2, I must be using Feature 1 (i.e X>Y), so the two are not independent at all.

EDIT: See comment below. The data can come as either paired or unpaired, whichever is easier.

```
I want to estimate E[Y], but I only have the arbitrary moments for X|Y=0, X|Y>0, and X.

How can I estimate E[Y]?
```

I would start with the [conditional expectation formula](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Etgk/464_07/cond_exp.pdf)

$f_{X|Y} (x|y) =\frac{f_{X,Y} (x, y)}{f_Y (y)}$

As I said, I can estimate both $f_{X|Y} (x|y=0)$ and $f_{X|Y} (x|y>0)$ with the data I have.

But I don't think I can estimate $f_{X,Y} (x, y)$, because to get $P(X \le x, Y \le y)$ would require (I think) knowing that $Y \le y$ but i have no idea about the length of $Y$ in the first place.

Does this all make sense? How can I proceed? What additional info would I need to estimate $f_{X,Y} (x, y)$? I still haven't used the fact that I know $f_X(x)$.

Comment: Are the observations of $X$ and $Y$ paired data? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_data for a definition.

Comment: Great clarifier...I can get both paired or unpaired comparisons, it's a very large dataset with many observations.

In other words, for a particular user U, I could get you a bunch of data points for X and X|Y=0 and X|Y>0  for that user U (and so we could use paired data over several such users U)

But l could also get you only distinct users' values for X and X|Y, so if it's easier to do an unpaired estimation we could do that too.

I hope this clears stuff up. We have a very large dataset, so we can find large samples of either paired or unpaired data

Comment: Suppose we had two "worlds" or data sets, with the same distribution of values $X$, and the same distribution of values $X$ among users who used Feature 2 at all. But in one, everyone who uses features 1 and 2 has $Y/X < 0.1$; in the other, everyone who uses features 1 and 2 has $Y/X > 0.9$. The three moments from both cases are exactly the same, so they tell you nothing about the $Y$ values.

Comment: Great example; that's sorta what I was thinking too...I thought of another example where X|Y looks WAY different than X *because of* Y, and so there's maybe not a good way to infer Y. Though this question seems like a natural question that maybe someone has come up with some estimation for, so I'll leave the question up anyway just in case.